# type of feature importance in XGBoost classifier

Tags: xgboost, xgbclassifier

I am using XGBClassifier with GridSearchCV(cv=KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=42, shuffle=True)). I want to explore variable importance, so I am getting it from the model.best estimator: `model.best_estimator_.feature_importances_`.
However, it is not clear what type of variable importance is used (gain, or weight).
When I am printing `model.best_estimator_.importance_type` I get None.
I remember I could print the type of variable when using XGBRegressor in the past.
Could someone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xgboost feature importance for classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76095884/xgboost-feature-importance-for-classification)