# xgboost feature importance for classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I am using `XGBClassifier` with

```
GridSearchCV(cv=KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=42, shuffle=True))
```

I want to explore variable importance.

Why does

```
model.best_estimator_.feature_importances_
```

give different values compared to the values returned from

```
model.best_estimator_.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='type')
```

for any type `['gain', 'weight', 'cover']` of feature importance used?

I would expect that the former uses one of the 3 types and thus in one case results overlap.